# bc: Why does `ibase=16; obase=10; FF` returns FF and not 255?

Tags: bc

I've been using `bc` to convert numbers between binary to hex, octal to decimal and others.

In the following example, I was trying to convert base 16 (hex) number to binary, octal and decimal.

I don't have any problem with the first 2 attempts.

```
$ echo 'ibase=16; obase=2; FF' | bc  
11111111
$ echo 'ibase=16; obase=8; FF' | bc 
377
```

But when I tried to convert base 16 (hex) number to base 10 (decimal), I was getting wrong answer. The answer should be `255`

```
$ echo 'ibase=16; obase=10; FF' | bc 
FF
```

Comment: For numbers smaller than a machine word (32 or 64 bits) in bash, you don't need bc: `printf '%d\n' 0x$hex` or just `echo $(( 0x$hex ))`

Comment: See the linked duplicate, specifically this in the accepted answer:"If you give ibase first instead, it changes the interpretation of the following obase setting"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Once `ibase=16` is done, further input numbers are in hexadecimal, *including* 10 in `obase=10` which represents the decimal value 16. So either set obase before, or set it after, using the new input base (now hexadecimal):

```
$ echo 'obase=10; ibase=16; FF' | bc
255
$ echo 'ibase=16; obase=A; FF' | bc
255
```

Comment: Theorem: Every multiplicative base written in itself is 10.

Comment: @Joshua, yea, that's pretty much the definition, I think.